# How can I fix list Array with the cursor data in Android

Tags: java, android

Hi i creata an aplication on android using SQL. I have problem when I want to set cursor. I don't know what I did wrong, becouse is my first program using Array list with cursor. Thanks for help.

```
public class ThoughtManager {

private Thought thought;
private ThoughtDbHelper dbHelper;
private Cursor cursor;
private Context context;

SQLiteDatabase db;
private ContentValues contentValues;
private ArrayList<Thought> allThoughts;
int iTitle;
int iDetail;
int iTime;
int iDate;
int iReason;
int iComment;

private String[] columns=new String[]{ThoughtDbHelper.KEY,
        ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE,
        ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL,
        ThoughtDbHelper.TIME,
        ThoughtDbHelper.DATE,
        ThoughtDbHelper.REASON,
        ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT}; // Tablica wypisywanych elementow

public ThoughtManager(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;        // CO tu dokładnie robimy????
    dbHelper=new ThoughtDbHelper(context);
    contentValues=new ContentValues();
}

public ThoughtManager openForWrite() // Gdy chcemy zapisywac cos w bazie nowego
{
    db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return  this;
}
public ThoughtManager openForRead() // Gdy chcemy odczytywac dane z bazy
{
    db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return  this;
}
public void close()
{
    dbHelper.close(); // Bezpieczne zamykanie aplikacji
}

public long createThought(Thought thought)  // TWORZE NOWY ELEMENT W BAZIE DANYCH!!!
{
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE, thought.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL, thought.getDetails());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME, thought.getTime());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE, thought.getDate());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON, thought.getReason());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT, thought.getComment());

    return db.insert(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
public int updateThought(Thought thought) // Edytuje element W BAZIE DANYCH!!!
{
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE, thought.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL, thought.getDetails());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME, thought.getTime());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE, thought.getDate());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON, thought.getReason());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT, thought.getComment());
    return db.update(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE + "=" + thought.getTitle(), null);
}
public int deleteThought(Thought thought) // Usuwa element W BAZIE DANYCH!!!
{
    return db.delete(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE + "=" + thought.getTitle(), null);
}

public ArrayList<Thought> getAllThoughts() // Pobieramy wszystkie elementy do tablicy
{

    //Cursor cursor=db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null,null,null,null,null);
    //cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor = db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ThoughtDbHelper.KEY,
            ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE,
            ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL,
            ThoughtDbHelper.TIME,
            ThoughtDbHelper.DATE,
            ThoughtDbHelper.REASON,
            ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT}, (String)null, (String[])null, (String)null, (String)null, (String)null);

    iTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE);
    iDetail=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL);
    iTime=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME);
    iDate=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE);
    iReason=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON);
    iComment=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT);
    // W petli wpisuje kolejno wszystkie dane do kolejnych tablic w zlaeznosic ile mamy elemetow
    for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()) // (zacznij od poczatku ; rózny(!) od ostatniego ; idz co jeden
    {
        thought=new Thought(cursor.getString(iTitle),  // pobieram tytul
                cursor.getString(iDetail), // poberam opis
                cursor.getString(iReason), // pobierma czas etc...
                cursor.getString(iComment),
                cursor.getString(iDate),
                cursor.getString(iTime));
        allThoughts.add(thought);
    }
    return  allThoughts;
}

public Thought getThought(Thought thought)
{
    cursor=db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    iTitle=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE);
    iDetail=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL);
    iTime=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME);
    iDate=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE);
    iReason=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON);
    iComment=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT);
    if(cursor!=null) // Jezeli mamy jakies dane
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst(); // przerzuc kursor do poczatku, by odczytywac dane od 1
        thought=new Thought(cursor.getString(iTitle),  // pobieram tytul
                cursor.getString(iDetail), // posberam opis
                cursor.getString(iReason), // pobierma czas etc...
                cursor.getString(iComment),
                cursor.getString(iDate),
                cursor.getString(iTime));
        allThoughts.add(thought);
    }
    return thought;
}
```

}

CatLog:

[image]

ThoughtDbHelper:

```
public class ThoughtDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//Zmienne do mojej bazy danych
static final String TITLE="title";
static final String DETAIL="detail";
static final String REASON="reason";
static final String COMMENT="comment";
static final String KEY="_id";
static final String DATE="date";
static final String TIME="time";
static final String TABLE_NAME="thought_tbl";
static final String DATABASE_NAME="thought_db.sql"; // nasza baza danych
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // wesja naszej bazy danych


private String QUERY_STRING="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "+KEY
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+ TITLE
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + DETAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + TIME
        + " TEXT, " + DATE + " TEXT, " + REASON + " TEXT, " + COMMENT
        + " TEXT )";

public ThoughtDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(QUERY_STRING);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

View Thought: There I want to view my saved thought

```
public class ViewThought extends ListActivity {

ThoughtManager manager;
ArrayList<Thought> allThoughts;
ArrayList<String> allTitles;
ListView listView;
Thought thought;
String titlePosition;
Dialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.view_thought);
    manager=new ThoughtManager(this);
    allTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    listView = getListView();
    //listView.setBackgroundResource();
    listView.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 15);
    listView.setFooterDividersEnabled(true);
    listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
    d
    allThoughts = manager.getAllThoughts();

    // Pobieram wszystkie zadania/notatki
    for (Thought thought : allThoughts) // od  d ostatniego elemetnu
    {
        allTitles.add(thought.getTitle());
    }
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,allTitles));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
 /*   titlePosition = allTitles.get(position);
    //thought=manager.getThought(titlePosition);

    dialog=new Dialog(ViewThought.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_details);
    // 1 sposob
    //dialog.setTitle("Thought Detail view");

    //2 sposob
    TextView tvTime,tvDetail,tvReason,tvComment;
    tvComment=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewComment);
    tvDetail=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewDetails);
    tvReason=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewReason);
    tvTime=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewTime);

    dialog.setTitle(thought.getTitle()); 
    tvComment.setText(thought.getComment());
    tvDetail.setText(thought.getDetails());
    tvReason.setText(thought.getReason());
    tvTime.setText("Created on"+thought.getDate()+"At "+thought.getTime()); 
    dialog.show();

    */

  }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? What is your exact problem, expectation and what do you have..?

Comment: I have error:  java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Where? Post your logcat.

Comment: And debuger show me, that problem is with cursor.

Comment: I can also show all of my project if could help.

Comment: Please post your `ThoughtDbHelper`, also, what is line `91` in `getAllThoughts`?

Comment: The  line 91 is cursor=db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ThoughtDbHelper.KEY....

Comment: I add ThoughtDbHelper in my question

Comment: You have initialized your database beforehands, and checked that `db` is not null, when you access it? (Add a breakpoint in line 79 and start your app in debug mode, hover db and see if it not null)

Comment: When i use debuger i see that db = null

Comment: What I should do, to make my bd is not null? I guess this is my problem?

Comment: why would you put a screen shot of the stacktrace? why do you not copy and paste the text?

Comment: you never call `openForWrite`, so your `db` object stays null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for a full walk-through.

You need to initialize your db, like:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

before you can read anything from it.

Comment: And what do you mena with getReadableDatabase()?

Comment: Following the official Tutorial (follow the above link!), you need a [Database Helper class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), which will get you a database.

Comment: I add all my code of ThoughtManager, could you look again. I will be very gratefull

Comment: Becouse it's still do not work

Comment: I Fix the problem. Now i have another ;/ when I want add thought to array list i have error., could you look what i do wrong? Code is the same like in my first question.